# What includes this ticket or What does this ticket include?

Tags: grammar

I suddenly made a "mistake" but I don't know if it's a mistake. So which is correct or they're both right?

Comment: They are both grammatical. They mean different things. Only one will be applicable to a given context.  What’s your context?

Comment: I mean what does this ticket have

Comment: Then you want, “What does this ticket include?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What includes this ticket?

You could ask this, for example, if you were comparing several vacation packages and you wanted to know which package includes a ticket for a particular attraction or excursion.

> What does this ticket include?

You would ask this if you wanted to know what attractions, excursions, meals, destinations, etc., are included if you buy a particular ticket.

Another way to ask this is, "What is included on [or with] this ticket?"

Answer (score 0):

Think of the ticket, a document describing something, as a container. it has something in it, something it is about. The ticket *includes* or contains one or more items.

The ticket is *about* one or more topics or items. The phrase *includes this ticket* is about a container of tickets. Your list of tickets *includes* this ticket.